# ¿Como sumar datos de un foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una duda, ¿como puedo sumar los valores del foreach? En este caso quiero sumar las ventas, para poder mostrar el total de ventas que tienen las asignaciones.

Una asignaciones puede tener muchas ventas.

```
<tbody>
  <?php $numero = 0; ?>
  @foreach ($asignaciones as $asignacion)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $numero = $numero +1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ $asignacion->fecha }}</td>
      <td>{{ $asignacion->user->nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ count($asignacion->ventas) }}</td>
  </tr>

  @endforeach
</tbody>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th width="20px">Total</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>?</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $numero = 0; $total = 0;
?>
  @foreach ($asignaciones as $asignacion)
  @php 
     $cantidad=count($asignacion->ventas);
     $total+=$cantidad;
  @endphp
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $numero = $numero +1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ $asignacion->fecha }}</td>
      <td>{{ $asignacion->user->nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ $cantidad) }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th width="20px">{{$total}}</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>?</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

cala con esto, (no lo he probado yo, seguro hay mas de un error por ahi.)

ahora bien, no es recomendable y de hecho se podría decir que es mala practica codear la lógica dentro de un view (venga la cantidad y el total) lo que podrías hacer es crear un método pequeño, testeable, en tu model que te de el arreglo con todos los valores ya listos para imprimir. (una ventaja seria que si quieres agregar mas elementos, no tendrás que aglutinar todo tu código en este archivo que se supone que nomas se dedica a imprimir la informacion).